# How to host ASP.NET MVC or Web.Api project on IIS without publishing? I'm using Visual studio 2022 and .Net8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I create an ASP.NET MVC 4 project and just build it in Visual Studio 2022.

Then I opened IIS and add an application under the site/Default Web Site with 'TestMvc' Alias.

Application pool is `defaultAppPool` under the .NET CLR version v4.030319.

Then I chose physical Path Root of the project like this `C:\Users\bishn\source\repos\TestMvc\TestMvc` and press ok.

I right click on the application which is `TestMvc` which I add in step 2 and click on Edit Permissions...  Than I go to security click on Edit After that click on Add Here i add two Users which are "IUSER" and "IIS_USERS" give them all permissions "Full Control" and press ok.

Now I close IIS and Visual Studio both. After that I go to Google Chrome and type "http://localhost/TestMvc" this url and I see my website there.

After some time I open my project in Visual Studio and made some changes to the `HomeController` and just build the project and refresh this "http://localhost/TestMvc" this page and I see my changes there. Where ever I made some changes in views (`.cshtml`) files then I just need to save that file and refresh the website in views I have no need to build.

**Notes**

1. In this whole process I'm using unpublished project.
2. I'm not running my website in Visual Studio by press F5/Start. I run it in localhost.
3. I'm not using debug/release folder as my physical Path in IIS Application I'm using Root folder of the project.
4. I'm also using W3WP.exe process in this case for debugging. I Attach the process and refresh website and simply debug the code.

**Now my question**

I did same thing with ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 8) but it's not working.

I read lots of things on the internet all those not working. People just talking same thing in most of the post/article/videos that is publish the project.

If I publish the project then how can I debug the project, If I publish the project in debug mode in this case I debug the project. But the problem is if I made some changes in views than why I do wait to see the changes, Firstly it's build the project and than it publish it. It's a time taking process/Slow development.

I don't want to publish my project and don't want to Run by visual studio by press f5/Run. I just want a clean setup as i did in MVC4 project.

**Note**: I already download .NET Core Hosting Bundle to my system. I create an application pool under the no "managed code". It's not working. I made some changes in IIS Modules, Handler Mappings, Application Settings etc those are suggested in post/article/videos which i read and see. Those are not working.

**Note**: I don't want to use any external tools or library which are not the part of .NET stack.

Comment: "I don't want to publish my project and don't want to Run by visual studio by press f5/Run" this seems [contradictory](https://xkcd.com/1172/) to standard practice.

Comment: @gunr2171 At the development time I don't want to Publish

Comment: I don't know the correct answer but in earlier versions of Visual studio there was option to create a website. Then on choosing web forms we create a website. This website can be hosted to IIS without publishing. We used to do this on live server. I suggest you to search for creating a website on .net 8.0 and not an app.

Comment: You are not the first beginners wanting to go off the route, but there isn't much to discuss. You don't want to, but you have to.